# Getting 'Empty' screenshot while running 'Android Emulator' in 'headless' mode

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium, headless

I'm trying to run my Appium code in 'Android Emulator' in 'Headless' (-no-window) mode.
And I'm facing the issue that screenshots stop working properly and return empty images.
Although they work fine when running Emulator with UI (without the '-no-window' option).
I also tried to take a screenshot with 'adb' and that doesn't work either

**Repro Rate: 4/5**

To reproduce, just run launch Emulator with '-no-window' param:

```
emulator -avd <emulator_name> -no-window
```

Then just keep capturing screenshot:

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png
```

You will notice that sometimes it will provide a regular screenshot, but rarely, and usually it will be a blank screenshot.

The same behavior with 'Appium' code:

```
self.driver.screenshot_as_png
```

Tried with different functions (with 'Selenium' functions as well), in different 'system-iamges' (Android Emulator API lvl), with different configs and nothing helps yet..

Anyone faced the same problem?
Haven't found a suitable solution for this yet.
Last but not least, I'm on macOS (13.0.1 (22A400))